# How to deal with: using features of my app in other app e.g Safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

This is a clearly theoretical question.

When I browsing App Store I found application called Tap-Translate. I'm author of other simple application (iWrapper) but this app interested me so much. I wonder, **How make something like this Tap-Translate's feature shown on screen**? I mean, user tap on word and Tap-Translate is called and **it shows** user some **custom popover** with translated words or something **in other app**.

Screen:

[image]

And the **main question** is:
What issues do I need to know to be able to invoke methods of my application from another application (like Safari)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvxWFcKdCHU), you'll see that it is a bit more complicated than that. It uses a bookmark that translates using javascript.

You can't really interfer with any other application in iOS, due to sandboxing (except using [custom url schemes](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)).

Good luck mate.